# Javascript validation error for hidden field using MVC4 Razor site with unobtrusive validation

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

While using ASP.NET MVC with unobtrusive validation enabled I have, on a number of occasions, had a need to embed an ID into a Razor form as a hidden field. I've learned to always include a validation message, for example:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ParentId)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ParentId)
```

If the validation message is left off, this will trigger a javascript error on submit, because the hidden field by default includes unobtrusive validation attributes which require a corresponding validation error message. 
I realize that I can get the html output that I'm looking for by hand-coding the field:

```
<input data-val="false" id="ParentId" name="ParentId" type="hidden" value="@Model.ParentId" />
```

But if I take this approach I lose the benefits of using the `InputExtensions.HiddenFor` helper method. Is there any way I can simply use the extension method without generating JavaScript errors?

**Edit:**

This was a jquery validate issue. My jquery validate script was stuck on version 1.8.1 (see note below). I manually updated to jquery.validate 1.11.1 and the problem disappeared.

*Note*:

The reason the jQuery validate wasn't updating is because the original jquery validate 1.8.1 scripts were not installed by NuGet. In this scenario, NuGet detects the library and offers to update, but when the update is executed the original scripts are not replaced. This is treated as a non-fatal warning by NuGet. Moral of the story: read all of your NuGet output!

Comment: You are absolutely wrong.  There is no requirement that there be a validation message on any MVC field, hidden or not.  The problem you were seeing in the past was likely that you were not actually setting a hidden value in your field, and as such was not posting a value.  The attributes only trigger a validation error if there is no value in the hidden.

Comment: My problem is with the InputExtensions.HiddenFor method. I've clarified my question.

Comment: No, you are absolutely wrong.  There is no requirement that there be a validation message on any MVC field, hidden or not, including InputExtensions methods.  You are simply wrong on this.  As long as there is a value in the hidden, and it does not violate any other validation that may be present on the field, then it will not generate an error.

Comment: Yes, I was absolutely and simply wrong. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: I'm confused why having an older version would cause this problem.  An older version should still work.  Regardless, I'm glad you fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wrong on this.

This code works perfectly fine:

```
@model MyViewModel;

@using(BeginForm()) {
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.HiddenId)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TextField);
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

model:

```
public class MyViewModel {
    public int HiddenId {get;set;}
    public string TextField {get;set;}
}
```

ActionMethods:

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    return View(new MyViewModel { HiddenId = 1, 
                TextField = "We Don't need no steekin Validation Messages" });
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
         return Content("It's Valid!");
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't try to reproduce this in an empty project, but I hadn't done that. With that as a guide, I was able to unravel the root of the problem (see updated question).

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood the question, but may be I missed something.
I use hidden fields to hold IDs of related records, and never used the validator approach.

If you need to use a hidden to hold the ID, is because you don't want/need to display that to the user and let him alter that value... so, a validator is should not be needed.

If this field is required, and since the user can't enter it... if this field is missing is an unexpected situation and need to be handled similar to an exception (not disclosing the origin of the error, since could be the user trying to alter your html using Firebug or crafting the post).

If your logic (JS/Razor) can put something in your hidden, but sometimes you need to place a null there, since ID normally start in 1, you can use numbers from 0 to negative values to representate a null value. Then, you can post the value and do a check in the controller.  If you use this approach, you could even use your validator logic.

Comment: The problem is that if you use the InputExtension.HiddenFor method, a validation message is always required. What I want is to not use a validator for the ID, like you, but to also enable unobtrusive validation for fields that support editing, and to use the HiddenFor method to generate the hidden ID field. I've clarified the question; hopefully this clears up the confusion.

Comment: Your example is what I use... all my edit views have one or several HiddenFor helpers and I don't use a validator.